# Permutations and combinations - choosing an integer

Tags: permutations

**Question:**

> In how many ways can we choose 2 distinct integers from 1 to 100 such that the difference between them is at most 10?

**Approach:**
I tried to fix a certain number, and then find the number of integers that would satisfy the condition However, this is a very long method. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say for every number from 1 to 90, you can count the ten integers that follow it.  $(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),\dot(1,11),(2,3),(2,4),\dots(2,12)\dots(90,100)$.   Oh, then add in the 9 pairs starting with 91, the 8 pairs starting with 92, 7 starting with 93 etc... Ending with $(99,100)$ which I think is a total of 945.

$90\times10+\frac{9\times10}{2}$

I don't think that double counts anything or misses any, does it?  I'll think it over for a second...

Comment: I came up with 945 too. But is there any easier method?

Comment: There might be.  Still turning it over...

Comment: The only other thing I can see is just taking every number from 1 to 99 and counting the 10 integers above them, $99\times10$ and then subtracting out the triangle of numbers that are greater than 100 $(45)$ to get $990-45=945$